# Ruby on Rails - undefined local variable or method (strong parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is using Rails 4.1.8 and I use Simple Form gem.
I get the undefined local variable or method error on the strong parameter definition under `private` and I don't understand the cause of this.

**_form.haml.html**

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    - if @recipe.errors.any?
        #errors
            %h2
                = pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") 
                prohibited this recipe from being saved
            %ul
                - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg

    = f.input :title
    = f.input :serving
    = f.input :prep
    = f.input :cook


    = f.button :submit
```

**controller**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save 
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: "Successfully created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end

    private

    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :serving, :prep, :cook)
    end

  end
end
```

[image]

And the submit button takes me to index route `http://localhost:3000/recipes` rather than 
show `http://localhost:3000/recipes/1`

Comment: I'm new to rails and I believe this kind of thing could happen. I will close/delete this question when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close `create` method properly. It should be:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save 
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: "Successfully created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :serving, :prep, :cook)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to rails and I thought `if else` doesn't require `end` and I used `end` to close private as well.

Comment: @SeongLee `if else` require `end` (unless it's one-line `if`). `private` doesn't require `end`.